Error "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors" even if the object is recursive, and the same operation in the same dataset gives no error
I am trying to select a subset of observations. I'm not sure what I'm doing makes sense since it involves two different datasets. Still, I'm bothered by receiving an error that, in my opinion, shouldn't be there and makes no sense: "$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors".
With the dataset "Anxiety", I run a set of commands without getting any error:
dim(Anxiety)
# [1]  69 41
dim(Anxiety_arm)
# [1] 123 355
Anxiety_arm= as.data.frame(Anxiety_arm)
dim(Anxiety_arm)
# [1] 123 355
Anxiety_arm=subset(Anxiety_arm,Anxiety$LeveloftreatmentInt1=="group")

Instead, with the dataset "PTSD", after running the same set of commands,
dim(PTSD)
# [1]  71 413
dim(PTSD_arm)
# [1] 130 350
PTSD_arm= as.data.frame(PTSD_arm)
dim(PTSD_arm)
# [1] 130 350 

I get an error with the last command:
PTSD_arm=subset(PTSD_arm,PTSD$LeveloftreatmentInt1=="group")

the error being:
Error in PTSD$LeveloftreatmentInt1 : 
operator is invalid for atomic vectors

However, by checking, I find that R-Studio tells me not only that "PTSD" is not an atomic vector:
is.atomic(PTSD)
# [1] FALSE

but also that it's recursive:
is.recursive(PTSD)
# [1] TRUE


If PTSD and PTSD_arm have two different row counts, what exactly do you want subset(PTSD_arm,PTSD$LeveloftreatmentInt1=="group") to do? Do you want to reply on vector recycling? It's easier to help you if you include a simple reproducible example with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Is there a column called PTSD inside the PTSD_arm data.frame?

Try: PTSD_arm=subset(PTSD_arm, LeveloftreatmentInt1=="group")

Thank you @Edward: in this case, I get the error message: "Error in eval(e, x, parent.frame()) :
object 'LeveloftreatmentInt1' not found"

@MrFlick: yes, there is.

@MrFlick: yours is a good point. I think I need to create the "_arm" datasets by adding the LeveloftreatmentInt1 variable.

Subsetting a data set using a variable from another dataset is just asking for trouble.
